# File upload issue if more than 2GB, request body exceeds maximum size (2147483647) for SSL buffer

Tags: java, file-upload, wicket-1.5

I am working on the web application that was developed in Java 1.8, Apache wicket 1.5.6 with embedded jetty server 8.1.16 and also developed few pages using Ext JS 3.4.1. Apache 2.4 has configured as reverse proxy for this application.

The problem is after enabling 2 factor authentication(2FA) and trying to upload more than 2 GB file, apache(proxy) server throws exception as
Re-negotiation handshake failed, referer:https:///ui/v2FJNs4Lej0jKivA6KUhqg/v2Fd9/Ns48e
request body exceeds maximum size (2147483647) for SSL buffer, referer: https:///ui/DXOKJCEAASQaiEwUH_0xOA/DXO6a/ADXe4

Multipart option is enabled for file uploading

httpd.conf:

#Proxy ui to jetty

```
<Location "/ui">
        ....
        ....
        SSLRenegBufferSize 2147483647

        # Forward the SSL info onto Jetty (GUI)
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
        ....
        ....
     
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui
</Location>
```

I am trying with wicket filter to block the request and update Content-Length to 0 before reaching the proxy server. But request is hitting proxy server first and then come to filter. It did not work.

Anybody was facing similar issue?. I may be doing wrong approach. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

I can provide more detail if still requires.

Comment: Hi guys, I am stuck in the upload. Please help on this if anyone had experienced similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty Server 8.x was End of Life back in 2014.

Support for `Content-Length` exceeding 2GB (actually [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)) was first added to Jetty in version 9.4.20.v20190813 as part of the effort around [Issue #3504](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3503).

Also, Jetty 9.4.x is now at End of Community Support.
See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958

Be aware of the security vulnerabilities in your version of Jetty.
See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security_reports.php

Consider using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` on the request side of your POST instead (this sends the data without using `Content-Length`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joakim Erdfelt.
I tried to set Transfer-Encoding: chunked to javascript header of POST request. I am getting below exception
Refused to set unsafe header "Transfer-Encoding"

Comment: code is 


document.getElementById('fileUpload').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const url = document.getElementById('form1').action;
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('fileUpload', document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0]); 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url,true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
  xhr.send(fd);
 });

Comment: Not possible with XMLHttpRequest, as you cannot set that Header (it's controlled by the user-agent), and the limit on size is based on `integer` which is 2GB.  You either have to send it normally (not via XMLHttpRequest), or in pieces (in 500MB parts?) controlled by yourself, or via websocket.